# Round robin load balancing options for a single client

Tags: http, iis, biztalk, load-balancing

We have a biztalk server that makes frequent calls to a web service that we also host.

The web service is hosted on 4 servers with a DNS load balancer sitting between them. The theory is that each subsequent call to the service will round robin the servers and balance the load.

However this does not work presumably because the result of the DNS lookup is cached for a small amount of time on the client. The result is that we get a flood of requests to each server before it moves on to the next.

Is that presumption correct and what are the alternative options here?

a bit more googling has suggested that I can disable client side caching for DNS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318803

...however this states the default cache time is 1 day which is not consistent with my experiences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we finally decided to go with was Application Request Routing which is an IIS extension. In tests this has shown to do what we want and is far easier for us (as developers) to get up and running as compared to a hardware load balancer.

http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting

Comment: NLBS is a free software solution with the Windows Servers - your server cluster gets a new IP address. It also has availability benefits, e.g. when deploying new versions to the servers, although NLBS doesn't monitor server availability at a per-service level (if it is pingable, the server stays in the cluster) http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/10/01/nlb-101-how-nlb-balances-network-traffic.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You need to load balance at a lower level with NLB Clustering on Windows or LVS on Linux (or other equivalent piece of software). If you are letting clients to the web service keep an HTTP connection open for longer than a single request/response you still might not get the granularity of load balancing you are looking for so you might have to reconfigure your application servers if that is the case.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the one client gets the response back almost instantly. I'm not sure what you mean about letting client keep the connection open though?

Comment: HTTP 1.1 allows clients and servers to exchange the keyword keep-alive in the Connection header field to indicate that they wish to keep the TCP connection open for additional request/response transactions. You'll want to disable this function on your servers force clients to initiate new TCP connections for each request if you want to load balance frequent requests from a single client.